# Upgrade the storage and/or provisioned IOPS on a reserved RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, iops

I would like to reserve an RDS instance, but as of right now my instance does not need a lot of storage provisioned. I would like to reserve the instance with 100GB and 500 IOPS provisioned, but I would like to increase this in the future if needed. Is this possible?